# Display filename without extension with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

when i uploaded a file, my view page will display the file
for example

'thisfile.jpg'

how do i remove .jpg and all file extension from the displayed file name.
i tried to go to the uploader and play around with the

# Override the filename of the uploaded files:

```
def filename
 xxx
end
```

but i have no idea what to type inside to remove the extension. I do not need versioning, i just wish to remove extension of filename display across all version.

thanks

Comment: Did you try to return only the file's basename from the filename method inside the uploader?

Comment: I would suggest to deal with filename format in the UI and not the carrierwave uploader.

Comment: my ui is

      td = " #{document.file_name}"

i tried changing to document.basename but the display is still with .jpg

what else do i need to do?

Comment: def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

Comment: It has nothing to do with store_dir.  The document.file_name evaluates to "thisfile.jpg" so you could: File.basename(document.file_name, ".*")

Comment: any news about this?

Answer (score 1):

In your picture_uploader.rb :

```
  def filename
     file = File.basename("#{original_filename}", ".*")
  end
```

`".*"` : This will give you the filename without the extension.

The outcome would be:

```
/path/to/your/file/originalname
```

without the extension.

To display `originalname` without the file path in your view, the code should look like:

```
<%= picture.filename_identifier %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just:

```
def filename
  basename = file.basename
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`# image.png --> "image"`

```
def filename
  basename = File.basename file.file, File.extname(file.file)
end
```